# Instantiating a WinForm in a Console Application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

When I run the following code both Forms "hangs". Any Idea why?

```
    static void Main()
    {

        Form f1 = new Form();
        f1.Show();

        Form f2 = new Form();
        f2.Show();


        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Hint: Look at the main method in a Windows application and see what additional stuff it has to process the forms. You'll need that here too. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you need to call `Application.Run` in order to process the window's messages.

If one of the forms is your "main window", i.e. you want the application to exit when the window closes, you should use `Application.Run(form)`.

If you want several windows with none of them being especially significant, use just `Application.Run()`, and decide on your own when to exit the application by calling `Application.Exit()`.

Another alternative is to call `Form.ShowDialog` on the second form. `ShowDialog` has its own message pump so while the second window is open, messages will be processed for both windows. But in this scenario, when the window on which you called `ShowDialog` is closed, the other window will be frozen.

Comment: That is what I was looking for. I didn't realize that i can run Application.Run() without a Form/ApplicationContext as parameter.

Answer (score 6):

Because there's no message loop in your thread.

To make a form working, you must open it through `Application.Run(form)` [(MSDN Link)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.run.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. It's that the only way to get the Form running?

Comment: Another way is to use `ShowDialog`, which does the message pumping on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any interaction on those forms or are they empty test ones?

I would have thought that code would launch the form on the same thread as the console window - and `Show()` blocks until the form being Shown exits. It may be that the console window blocks as well, giving you a deadlock. I'd expect the console execution to continue once you close f1, if you're able to.

edit: other answers have shown me to be completely wrong. Ignore what I've said. In any case, I think it's actually `ShowDialog()` on a dialog window that blocks, not `Show()`.